# Proxy in .net

Tags: c#

I tried accessing web for xml parsing using the code below:

```
        System.Uri proxy = new System.Uri("http://usr:pwd@10.1.121.2:8080");
        System.Net.WebRequest.DefaultWebProxy = new System.Net.WebProxy(proxy);
        string url = "http://url/";
        XmlTextReader reader = new XmlTextReader(url);
        richTextBox1.Text = Convert.ToString(reader.Read());
```

But it's giving an error that proxy authentication needed. I have set the proxy parameters already. So can someone suggest changes needed to make it work?

Comment: I don't know much C#, but is System.Uri really so clever that it automagically parses and understands the user and password in the first string?

Comment: I use to give it this way in python. I am new to C#. I taught it would work...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
WebProxy proxy = new WebProxy("172.0.0.1:8080", true);    
proxy.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("user", "passw", "domain");
```

Then, use WebRequest to retrieve the data stream through the proxy.

```
WebRequest dstream = WebRequest.Create("http://data-stream-url.com/file.ext");
dstream.Proxy = proxy;
```

Comment: even after giving this its raising exception as "The remote server returned an error: (407) Proxy Authentication Required"

Comment: Is it possible you are not authenticating properly with the proxy server?

Comment: the proxy is now working but I need to know how to get xml from the web request object?

Comment: Take a look at the following link, and combine it with my answer above: http://www.noboxsolutions.com/xmltextreader_stream.aspx

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to set `Credentials` property on the `WebRequest.DefaultWebProxy` object. `CredentialCache.DefaultNetworkCredentials` might do the job.